# Why can't I concatenate a string inside of a link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concatenation

Ruby: 2.2.3

Rails: 4.2.4

OS: OSX 10.11.2 Beta

I'm learning Rails, and when I was making a `link_to` like this:

```
<% link_to 'Visit Url', 'http://#{@link.url} %>
```

It did not link to external sites if link.url was something like "Google.com".  Instead, it did not use the variable at all and created a static link that always created an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="http://#{@link.url}">Visit Url</a>
```

Separating the string from the variable like this did link properly to an external site:

```
<% link_to 'Visit Url', 'http://' + @link.url %>
```

So why does the first one not work?  If link.url is "google.com", shouldn't the first `link_to` properly concatenate to "http://google.com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `"` double quotes instead of the `'` single quotes. Anything within single quotes is not interpolated.

So:

```
@link = "www.google.com"
s1 = 'http://#{@link}'
s2 = "http://#{@link}"

puts s1 # prints http://#{@link}
puts s2 # prints http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I never knew that single quotes vs double quotes made a difference.